# Laravel one click sorting

Tags: php, laravel, sorting, laravel-5

I'm new on this Laravel and was trying to play around the Laravel's quickstart project. I'm not familiar with the variable set within the template. I'm trying to **create a one button/link to sort by ascending or decending** all the retrieved records.

Usually I have no problem with basic PHP sorting by using `switch ()`, but since I'm using Laravel, things are getting a little bit unfamiliar to me. So here's the code:-

**routes.php**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

Route::get('/sort/{id}', function ($id)  { // get to the sorted page ("/sort") 
    switch ($id) {
            case 'asc' :
                return view('tasks', [ // get the tasks table from the database
                'tasks' => Task::orderBy('name', 'asc')->get(),
                'sort' => "desc"
                // From the tasks table, get the listing from the table and arrange them descending by date of creation 
            ]);
            case 'desc' :
                return view('tasks', [ // get the tasks table from the database
                'tasks' => Task::orderBy('name', 'asc')->get(), 
                'sort' => "asc" // From the tasks table, get the listing from the table and arrange them ascending by date of creation 
            ]);
        }
    });
```

**tasks.blade.php**

```
<div class="panel-body">
                        <table class="table table-striped task-table">
                            <thead>
                                <th><a href="/sort/{{$sort}}">Task</a></th>
                                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @foreach ($tasks as $task) <!-- display the listings from the tasks table -->
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="table-text"><div>{{ $task->name }}</div></td>
                                        <td class="table-text"><div>{{ $task->description }}</div></td>

                                        <!-- Task Delete Button -->
                                        <td>
                                            <form action="{{ url('task/'.$task->id) }}" method="POST"> <!-- form action select the id on the task table database($task->id) -->
                                                {{ csrf_field() }}
                                                {{ method_field('DELETE') }} <!-- delete the field -->

                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-btn fa-trash"></i>Delete
                                                </button>
                                            </form>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
```

I just refer some of the codes on the internet and make some of my own as I'm not used with the variable within the HTML part in Laravel. I thought it would work but when I run the code, it throws the `undefined variable: sort` in the `tasks.blade.php`. Usually any variable is within the backend PHP, but this is a whole new environment to me. So, I wonder **how does variable in HTML works?** and **how to make the sort working?**

**EDIT 1:**

Screenshot of error:-

[image: Error]
[image: Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution for my own question. Instead of using `{{$sort}}` in the `tasks.blade.php` which I haven't set any default key, I need to use `isset()` function to check whether the variable is set accordingly or not. Since Laravel have its own function for that, I just use them:-

```
{{{ isset($sort) ? $sort : 'asc' }}}
```

This mean that it will set the default initial `$sort` variable into ascending (`asc`).

That's the answer for it. Thank you, me!

Answer (score 0):

Your sort doesn't work, because you sort Task model ascending in both cases. You should use

`Task::orderBy('name', 'desc')->get()`

in second case. About variable it would be more clear if you provide screenshot.

Comment: Ops.. my bad.. Still, I have problem with the undefined variable error in the tasks.blade.php. I have provided the screenshot of the error.